# Saving multiple figures from each file for multiple files separately

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a code that can read and run multiple files and generates multiple figures from each file. I want to save all the figures separately. But I can save only one figure from each file. For example, I have 17 files, each file generates 3 figures, so I should have 51 figures in total. The code displays all the 51 figures(3 from each file) but saves only one figure from each file, 17 figures in total. How can I save all the figures separately?

```py
    import os
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    for file in os.listdir(r'/mydir'):
        if file.endswith(".txt"):
            print(os.path.join("/mydir", file))
            life_time= pd.read_csv(file, sep = "\t")
            life_time.columns = ["Time" , "Counts"]
            time= life_time.Time[2:599]
            time_1=time-1e-06
            x1=time_1.reset_index(drop=True)
            bin1 = life_time.Counts[2:599]
            bin2 = life_time.Counts[602:1199]
            bin3 = life_time.Counts[1202:1799]
            """Reser the index"""
            r_bin1=bin1.reset_index(drop=True)
            r_bin2=bin2.reset_index(drop=True)
            r_bin3=bin3.reset_index(drop=True)


            x= x1[1:598]
            y1=r_bin1[1:598]
            y2=r_bin2[1:598]
            y3=r_bin3[1:598]
    #From each dataset I have created three y value such as y1, y2, y3 and then created a list
            y = [y1, y2, y3]
            def exponenial_func(x, a, b, c):
                return a*np.exp(-b*x)+c
            for i in y:
                popt, pcov = curve_fit(exponenial_func, x, i)
                a, b, c = popt
                yy = exponenial_func(x, *popt)
                plt.plot(x,i)
                plt.plot(x, yy, 'r--')
                plt.savefig("file{}.jpg".format(file), dpi = 600, bbox_inches = "tight")
                plt.show()
```

For example, my file names are USA_1, USA_2......etc. I want to save the figure  with the figure name USA_1_bin1, USA_1_bin2, USA_1_bin3, USA_2_bin1, USA_2_bin2, USA_2_bin3....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are overwriting your plot three times. Try this instead:

```
savename = f'{file}'+'_bin'+str(y.index(i)+1)+'.jpg'    
plt.savefig(savename, dpi = 600, bbox_inches = "tight")
```

As kingfischer suggested, I also like it more explicit myself, but it should not be required to work in this instance.

edit: Considering y is actually a list of Series the below is a more appropriate solution:

```
for count, i in enumerate(y):
    #other code
    savename = f'{file}'+'_bin'+str(count+1)+'.jpg'    
    plt.savefig(savename, dpi = 600, bbox_inches = "tight")
```

Comment: I was trying to follow your method, but I'm getting the following error:

savename = f'{file}'+'_bin'+str(y.index(i)+1)+'.jpg'

  File "//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1555, in __nonzero__
    self.__class__.__name__

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: Seems like y is a pandas Series? Don't have access to a pc now but you could try:    savename = f'{file}'+'_bin'+str(y.tolist().index(i)+1)+'.jpg'

Comment: Yes, y is a pandas series and tolist() didn't work here

Comment: Just some quick testcode:

    import pandas as pd
    i= 2
    y = pd.Series([1, 2, 3])
    file = 'filename'
    savename = f'{file}'+'_bin'+str(y.tolist().index(i)+1)+'.jpg'
    print(savename)

results in:
    filename_bin2.jpg

which is indeed the name you want right?

Comment: Initially, all the values were in dataframe. Then I created y list as you can see in my code. Yes, I want Filename_bin2/filename_y2, either one is fine

Comment: I'm editing my code and showing the full code. Please take a look

Comment: Ah oké, I misunderstood and assumed it was 1 value for y1 etc.

Easiest way to solve this is probably to use enumerate so that would become: for count, i in enumerate(y): and then use savename = f'{file}'+'_bin'+str(count+1)+'.jpg'

Answer (score 0):

I think you've left out the part of the code that does the actual plotting. Could you add it, or something representative? Without seeing it, my guess is that you're generating 3 figures each loop, but by calling `plt.savefig()` you're only referring to the last figure generated. For example, if you do this:

```
for file in os.listdir(r'/mydir'):
    data = # something that reads your .txt file into an array or dataframe
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(data[0], data[1])  # first graph
    plt.figure()
    plt.scatter(data[0], data[2])  # second graph
    plt.figure()
    plt.hist(data[3])  # third graph
    plt.savefig(f"file{file}.jpg")  # f-strings are super cool!
```

You will generate 3 separate figures, but will only save the last one because you haven't actually specified which figure you want to save. The interpreter just assumes you're interested in the last figure. A quick way around this is to pass your figures to variables, like so:

```
for file in os.listdir(r'/mydir'):
    data = # something that reads your .txt file into an array or dataframe

    fig1 = plt.figure()
    plt.plot(data[0], data[1])  # first graph
    fig2 = plt.figure()
    plt.scatter(data[0], data[2])  # second graph
    fig3 = plt.figure()
    plt.hist(data[3])  # third graph

    # now we can refer to the figures by variable name as save them
    fig1.savefig(f"file{file}_1.jpg")
    fig2.savefig(f"file{file}_2.jpg")
    fig3.savefig(f"file{file}_3.jpg")
```

This will now create the same 3 figures, but will save each one separately. However I'm not a fan of this method because just calling `plt.plot()` still assumes you mean the last active figure. Something more explicit will leave no room for error, so I much prefer this:

```
for file in os.listdir(r'/mydir'):
    data = # something that reads your .txt file into an array or dataframe
    # First create your figures and axes
    fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
    fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots()
    fig3, ax3 = plt.subplots()

    # Then plot your data on the specific axes
    ax1.plot(data[0], data[1])  # first graph
    ax2.scatter(data[0], data[2])  # second graph
    ax3.hist(data[3])  # third graph

    # now we can refer to the figures by variable name as save them
    fig1.savefig(f"file{file}_1.jpg")
    fig2.savefig(f"file{file}_2.jpg")
    fig3.savefig(f"file{file}_3.jpg")
```

You can also reference the `ax1, ax2, ax3` `matplotlib.axes` objects to change formatting as much as you want, and nothing will get mixed up or rely on the order you write it in your code.

Comment: Great! My answer remains though: you're just calling `plt.plot()` twice and then `plt.savefig()` instead of actually using an the method of the figure object. `plt.savefig()` will just refer to the last figure. If you create figures and axes using `plt.subplots()` you can then save those figures specifically using `fig1.savefig()`, as per my last code example.